# How to use org-tag-persistent-alist AND per-file dynamic tags

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

Reading the org manual about setting global/per-file tags, I wonder if it is possible to use `org-tag-persistent-alist` AND per-file dynamic tags.

When using `org-set-tags-command`, I’d like to select from a list comprising both:

1. the list of predefined tags in `org-tag-persistent-alist`
2. the list of all the tags that are already in use in the current buffer (some of which might not be in the persistent alist). I don’t want to pre-define these tags using a `#+TAGS` keyword at file-level. I want the actual tags attached to some headline in the buffer.

[The manual says](https://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-Tags.html):

> If you have globally defined your preferred set of tags using the
> variable org-tag-alist, but would like to use a dynamic tag list in a
> specific file, add an empty ‘TAGS’ keyword to that file

And then it says:

> If you have a preferred set of tags that you would like to use in every
> file, in addition to those defined on a per-file basis by ‘TAGS’
> keyword, then you may specify a list of tags with the variable
> org-tag-persistent-alist.

I tried to combine both behaviors by putting an empty ’#+TAGS:’ keyword at
the top of my file. But this still only gives me the tags in
`org-tag-persistent-alist`. What would be the best way to add to this list, for
completion, the tags already used in the buffer?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the current code: see [the code that calculates the completion table](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org.el#n12186) and note (l.12191) that `or`: `org-current-tag-alist` at that point is equal to `org-tag-persistent-alist`, so since that is non-nil, the call to `org-get-buffer-tags` is skipped. You'd need to rewrite the code.

Comment: Thanks @NickD. You're right, looking at the code I'm now rather pessimistic. It would be overkill to override `org-set-tags-command` just for this. Perhaps what I'll do then is write a function that gets triggered on every save, to puts the result of `(org-get-buffer-tags)` in the `#+TAGS:` keyword. From there, the local buffer tags are added to the persistent ones, which is what I need.